# Tensor product of complexification

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra, almost-complex

I am working with the definition of complexification $V_\mathbb{C}= V \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ where V is a real vector space, in order to better understand forms and vectors of type (p,q) when $V$ is itself endowed with an (almost) complex structure $J:V\rightarrow V$.

I am trying understand formulas like
$$
\Lambda ^k V_\mathbb{C} = \left(\Lambda^k V\right) \otimes \mathbb{C}
$$
but in order to work with wedge products I first need to convince myself that
$$
(V\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}) \otimes_\mathbb{C} (V\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C})
\simeq (V\otimes_\mathbb{R} V)\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}
$$
I am trying to come up with a proof interpreting 2-tensors as bilinear maps but I can't seem to find a nice and simple formula for the isomorphism. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you denote $\Lambda^kV$?

Comment: By $\Lambda^k V$ I mean the antisymmetric k-tensor product of $V$ over the real numbers.

Comment: See Corollary 6.25 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf.

Comment: Thank you! I found some notes by Keith Conrad but didn't know about this (so much more complete) version!